# Intellij IDE giving PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am getting error

```
22:00:17.222 [pool-6-thread-1] ERROR ingrian.internal.xml.XMLAuthToken - handshakeCompleted: SSL handshake did not complete within alloted time {}
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
```

in my Intellij IDE, when I am running any Java file, but when I am running `mvn clean install`, the build is getting successful. I have added all the required certificates.
mvn --version

```
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.4/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_351, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_351.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
```

IDE Run Config

[IDE Run Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDOq8.png)

Intellij was running fine, before, I replaced the old certs with the new certs and then it started giving this error.

I have downloaded new java version, new IDE version as well, cleared the old cache, but nothing seems to work.

Is there any configuration in Intellij that I have to update?

Comment: Try to import your certificates to the JRE used by maven. (Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner | JRE)

Comment: Use a more recent version of Maven... current version 3.8.6 ...

Comment: @EgorKlepikov yeah I installed my certificates under the JRE used by mvn.

Comment: @khmarbaise, mvn build command is running fine, its the IDE that is giving the cert issue

Comment: Than upgrade your IDE version...which version of IDEA do you use?

Comment: @khmarbaise, I am using the latest version (IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3 (Community Edition))

Comment: Try to install the certs into the keystore of the JVM that is used to run IntelliJ IDEA and is displayed in Help | About. Please see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000094584-IDEA-Ultimate-2016-3-4-throwing-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-when-trying-to-refresh-gradle?page=1#community_comment_115000405564

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this error while on MACOS. My Issue was when trying to download dependencies located in `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/2.0.7/slf4j-simple-2.0.7.pom` from maven central while using Intellij Idea.

Steps to resolve:

1. Visit `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/2.0.7/slf4j-simple-2.0.7.pom` on my browser.
2. Click the lock icon as below
   [![enter image description here][1]][1] Go to `Connection is secure` then `Certificate is valid`.
3. On the Details tab, select the top most on the certificate hierarchy and export to your known location on disc.

Next we are going to import the certificate on two keystores. First on our JDK keystore and later on the keystore used by the IDE.

Import on JDK keystore.

1. Navigate to security folder on JAVA_HOME. For my case locate `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.16.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security`. If list you will see a file `cacerts` which is a collection of trusted certificates. we need to import our downloaded certificate here using the command `sudo keytool -importcert -alias maven -file ~/Desktop/repo.maven.apache.org.cer -keystore cacerts`. Note for my case I downloaded the certificate to trust on my Desktop folder and named `repo.maven.apache.org.cer`. When prompted enter you password and `changeit` for truststore.
2. Next we need to trust the certificate within our IDE's security folder.  `cd /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 19.05.39.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/lib/security`. Note my IDE's version as the location my change abit based on the version of IDE you are using.
3. Import the downloaded certificate using `sudo keytool -importcert -alias maven -file ~/Desktop/repo.maven.apache.org.cer -keystore cacerts`. Enter your user password when prompted and `changeit` for keystore password.
4. Restart your IDE.

Comment: for the step 2 and 3, it can be simplified by adding directly in IDEA: Settings/tools/Server certificates then + the certificate downloaded.

Comment: I tried adding as you have mentioned @Young but didn't work for my case.